# Extract number after specific character in dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data frame with this structure:

```
var            
A1sometext_r2
BXother_r11
A1sometext_r4
C7sometext_r8
```

And would like a new column that stores the number that follows the "r"

```
var             new  
A1some9text_r2   2
BXother_r11      11
A1sometext_r4    4
C7sometext_r8    8
```

I'm trying to incorporate into a pipe so Tidyverse would be better

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can do it like this:

```
tibble(var = paste0('lala_r', sample(1:20, 15))) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    new = stringr::str_replace_all(var, '.*_r([0-9]*)$', '\\1'),
    new = as.integer(new)
  )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 2
   var        new
   <chr>    <int>
 1 lala_r8      8
 2 lala_r11    11
 3 lala_r16    16
 4 lala_r7      7
 5 lala_r1      1
 6 lala_r10    10
 7 lala_r12    12
 8 lala_r9      9
 9 lala_r18    18
10 lala_r6      6
11 lala_r3      3
12 lala_r20    20
13 lala_r4      4
14 lala_r14    14
15 lala_r15    15
```

Comment: regular expressions, did not thought of that